# What the right way unescape html entities in Angular?

Tags: angular, escaping

I get html entities from json file, like: `&#8217;`
How can I unescape it in html component?

I created custom pipe, but it works only for entities like `&amp;`:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {unescape} from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
  name: 'unescape'
})
export class UnescapePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return unescape(value);
  }

}
```

- I'm working with Angular 5.

Comment: Related [Unescape HTML entities in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9):

The solution, create next custom pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'unescape'
})
export class UnescapePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, 'text/html');
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Still the same : use replace or encodeUri of JavaScript and escape every chars you don't want. The other way is to create a Pipe like you are doing based on regex/replace/escape functions ;)

```
escape(htmlInput) { 
    htmlInput.replace("&amp;", "and")
}
```

`escape` is now encodeUri and you can also use contains to verify first if you have a matched pattern :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be relevant to the question. The question isn't how to escape a url, it's how to *un*escape it.